# Symfony 2 : render string as choice in a form

Tags: symfony

I have a entity, **Comment**. and when a user adds a comment, besides the comment he gives, he can choose between "good", "OK", "bad" etc.

I know how to do it by using two related entities, one for **Comment**, another for the **choice** ("good", "bad", etc). then create a relation between these two entities.

But it seems like an overkill for this. Anyone knows a simple way to achieve it? I wish I can save the choice as a string, but render it as a choice in the comment form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just save it as a string along with the comment. In your Comment FormType, just add a field for the rating, something like:

```
$builder->add('rating', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'good' => 'Good',
        'ok' => 'OK',
        'bad' => 'Bad',
    )
));
```

And in your Comment Entity, just add the corresponding field and setter/getter.